# Is “as” used even with phrases?

Tags: grammar

I know that the question “as vs. like” was already asked, but in the book “The Elements of Style” the author explains:
“Like—Not to be used for the conjugation ‘as.’ ‘Like’ governs nouns and pronouns; before phrases and clauses the equivalent word is ‘as’.”

—wrong: “We spent the evening like in the old days.”

—right:”We spent the evening as in the old days.”

So, are these sentences correct?

“He moved as a weird duck.”

“He moved as a duck on water.”

Comment: Are you sure the line is not “as *in* the old days”?  As you have it, it is very unnatural to me.  “a weird duck” or “a duck on water” is a **noun phrase** and should have *like*.

Comment: Sorry! You are right.

Comment: I don't have my Strunk&White handy at the moment, but please edit to quote the passage. I think you've misunderstood it; "as" should only be used with *clauses*, which have a verb. So, "as a duck *does*" would be right, but "She walks in beauty, *like* the night." Also note, this "rule" is so often broken that it's questionable whether it should be enforced. You won't "sound wrong" if you use it, but to tell others they're wrong for breaking it is perhaps unreasonable today.

Comment: @ Andy Bonner—thank you. The book says: “Like—Not to be used for the conjugation ‘as.’ ‘Like’ governs nouns and pronouns; before phrases and clauses the equivalent word is ‘as’.”—wrong: “We spent the evening like in the old days.” —right:”We spent the evening as in the old days.”

Comment: “We spent the evening like in the old days” may be textbook wrong, but common in casual speech. Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambridge Dictionary tells you:

> The prepositions **as** and **like** have different meanings. As + noun means 'in the role of', like + noun means 'similar to' or 'in the same way as'.

So, for example, one might say "*Speaking **as** a friend...*" to indicate that, while they might also have other relationships with you (ie a person might be your colleague *and* a friend) they are speaking from the position or role of friend. But, if you said a person was "*speaking **like** a friend*", that would suggest the manner in which they were speaking is how a friend would speak, and not necessarily that the person *is* a friend.

So, you're probably wondering which should be used in your example. That's where it gets tricky, because *neither* of your examples are particularly idiomatic.

You're comparing an evening in the present (or near past) to the 'old days'. Because it is a comparison, 'like' seems most appropriate. I would use the word 'like' in that context this way:

> The evening felt just like the old days.

However, there several *adverbial phrases* that contain both 'like' and 'as', which could be used in the context of your example:

> - We spent the evening **like we did** in the old days.
> - We spent the evening **as we did** in the old days.

Both of these adverbial phrases are comparing the old state to the new; however, there is a subtle difference:

- "*As it was*" emphasises the accuracy or truthfulness of the comparison. It suggests that the situation or condition being referred to is exactly the same as it was before.
- "*Like it was*" is more flexible and can suggest a comparison that is less precise or exact. It may imply a similarity rather than an identical state.

Comment: @ Astralbee. Thank you for explaining it!—I knew that we can use as+noun—“As your father, I’ll help you as much as I can.” (I’m your father.) Whereas—“Like your father, I’ll help you as much as I can.” (I’m not your father.) So, as a general rule, I should use “like” for nouns and noun phrases, and “as” for clauses.

Comment: @Piermo no you should use 'like' for loose comparisons where things are similar, 'as' for more direct comparisons where things are the same.

Comment: @Astrallbe. Got it. Thank you.